# What shape should openCV color image take for copyMakeBorder?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have a 3-channel color image and I'd like to extract a subimage with a reflected border using openCV `copyMakeBorder`.  Should the shape of the image be (3, H, W ) or ( H, W, 3 ) or what?

I *believe* openCV uses Numpy arrays.  Suppose I have a 512x512x3 color image, which would be an array with shape=[512,512,3].  When I invoke `cv2.copyMakeBorder` on the whole image with a border width of 32 all around and border treatment "reflect", I want to get back an image represented by a [576,576,3] array, **not** a [512,512,67] array.  So, the order of the axes matters.  Sorry that I don't have any code to point to, I was trying to understand before I code.

Comment: how your image is stored now? np.array?

Comment: Please share your current code, a representative image, details of what you want to extract and the expected result so we can help you sensiby. Thank you.

Comment: you have an image, what shape is it now, and why is the required shape in question?

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and add all the details, images and code in there rather than in comments which are unformatted and harder to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just try it...

```
>>> im=np.random.randint( (32,32,3) )
>>> im.shape
(3,)
>>> im=np.random.randint(0,255,(32,32,3))
>>> im.shape
(32, 32, 3)
>>> cv2.copyMakeBorder
<built-in function copyMakeBorder>
>>> imb = cv2.copyMakeBorder( im, 8, 8, 8, 8, 3 )
>>> imb.shape
(48, 48, 3)
>>> im2=np.random.randint(0,255,(3,32,32))
>>> im2.shape
(3, 32, 32)
>>> cv2.copyMakeBorder(im2,8,8,8,8,3).shape
(19, 48, 32)
```

So, as I suspected, the order of axes *does* matter, and the correct order is
`[row,col,color]`.  In the example above, `im2`, which is `[color,row,col]`,
misbehaves.